# Windows phone: Animate usercontrol from parent class file

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

In my Windows Phone app, I have a parent class file inherriting from UserControl, and multiple objects inheriting from that class. So the parent class, Parent.cs, is not partial.
Subclasses, are xaml objects, with xaml file and cs file.

I want to enable movements for all children, and am thus trying to achieve this in parent class.

Here is my code:

```
    this.MoveObjectX = new DoubleAnimation();
    this.MoveObjectY = new DoubleAnimation();
    this.MoveObjectX.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
    this.MoveObjectY.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);

    this.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();

    Storyboard.SetTarget(this.MoveObjectX, this.RenderTransform);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(this.MoveObjectY, this.RenderTransform);

    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(
            this.MoveObjectX,
            new PropertyPath(CompositeTransform.TranslateXProperty));
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(
            this.MoveObjectY,
            new PropertyPath(CompositeTransform.TranslateYProperty));

    this.storyboardMoveObject = new Storyboard();
    this.storyboardMoveObject.Children.Add(this.MoveObjectX);
    this.storyboardMoveObject.Children.Add(this.MoveObjectY);

    this.storyboardMoveObject.Completed += new EventHandler(storyboardMoveObject_Completed);
```

But it does not work. Code complies and runs, but the children won't move.
I must add that in each child, I set the doubleanimations from and to numbers.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: where is this code located and how do you call it?

Comment: This code is correctly called, but I am actually not sure that this architecture can work: Parent.cs (not partial) that extends UserControl, and children (xaml and code behind, partial) that extend Parent.cs. I mean it works, but apparently not with storyboards and CompositeTransform. I really don't know what could do the trick here.

Comment: @no, my question is, if this code is inside a virtual method, protected method, or where

Comment: Ok, here's the process: 1. The code above is in a private method being called in the class's constructor. 2. The storyboard.Begin method is called in an internal method in the same class (MoveObject()) 3. In the method: storyboardMoveObject_Completed, MoveObject is called again.

Comment: So there's no inherited logic in there. The movement must be the same for all sub classes, which is why I want to put it in the super class.

Comment: Tried to replace part of the code with these lines:

    Storyboard.SetTarget(this.MoveObjectX, this);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(this.MoveObjectY, this);

    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(this.MoveObjectX, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"));
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(this.MoveObjectY, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"));

But then I got a "Cannot resolve TargetProperty (UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX) on specified object".

Answer (score 0):

If the code to do the movement is called from the constructor of the parent as you mention in the comments, you need to call the parent's constructor in the constructors of the children. It is not automatic, that is why your code never gets called for the children.

The easiest way to called the parent's constructor is to append base()

```
public child():base() { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do call the base constructor. The code is called and is executed. Proof is that in my stotryboard_completed method, I check the X and Y position of the object, and when it reaches some specifica values, I remove the object from the screen, which correctly happens. What does not happen, is the actual movement. The object does not move on the screen. The storyboard happens, does its job of updating the CompositeTransform, but the object stays still...

Answer (score 0):

Alright got my own error: I was replacing RenderTransform with some other transform in sub classes. I just started to use a TransformGroup and everything works fine!

Thanks for your help